# My value isn't updating in the when i select an option React

Tags: reactjs

so basically i want to print the value i select in the dropdown
match is an array of three strings, firstname lastname and email

```html
//this is where i update by data its a bropdown
<select name="columns" id="headers" style={{ display: "flex", float: "right" }} onChange={(e)=> { handlematch(e.target.value, index1); }} Value={match[index1]} >
  <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>
    {/* Select the Column Name */} {match[index1]}
  </option>
  {match.map((attr, index) => { return (
  <option value={match[index]}>
    {match[index]}
  </option>
  ); })}
</select>






//this is where i want to update my data
<ul>
  <li style={{ fontWeight: "500", color: "#50535b" }}>
    <CheckCircleIcon fontSize="small" style={{ color: "green", padding: "2px" }} /> Matched to the{" "}
    <span class="suggested-fieldname primaryTextColor">
                                { match[index1] }
                              </span>{" "} field.
  </li>
  {/*
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>100% of your rows have a value for this column
  </li> */}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in this code

```
{match.map((attr, index) => { return (
  <option value={match[index]}>
    {match[index]}
  </option>
  ); })}
```

just type attr its basically the same as match[index]
and where you get the index1

Comment: that doesnt work i tried .. though I got the solution its something related to pointer.thanks though

Comment: if its not a problem i want to see the component maybe the problem is there